# Interpolating array columns with PiecewisePolynomial in scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate each column of a numpy array using scipy's `PiecewisePolynomial`. I know that this is possible for scipy's `interp1d` but for piecewise polynomial interpolation it does not seem to work the same way. I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

x1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
y1=np.array([[2,3,1],[4,1,6],[1,2,7],[3,1,3]])
interp=interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x1,y1,axis=0)

x = np.array([1.2, 2.1, 3.3])

y = interp(x)
```

Which results in `y = np.array([2.6112, 4.087135, 1.78648])`. It seems that only the first column in `y1` was taken into account for interpolation. How can I make the method return the interpolated values of each column in `y1` at the points specified by `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial` inteprets the different columns of `y1` as the derivatives of the function to be interpolated, whereas `interp1d` interprets the columns as different functions.

It may be that you do not actually want to use the `PiecewisePolynomial` at all, if you do not have the derivatives available. If you just want to have a smoother interpolation, then try `interp1d` with, e.g.,  `kind='quadratic'` keyword argument. (See the documentation for `interp1d`)

Now your function looks rather interesting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = linspace(0,5,200)
ax.plot(x, interp(x))
ax.plot(x1, y1[:,0], 'o')
```

[image]

If you try the quadratic spline interpolation:

```
interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x1, y1.T, kind='quadratic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = linspace(1,4,200)
ip = interp(x)
ax.plot(x, ip[0], 'b')
ax.plot(x, ip[1], 'g')
ax.plot(x, ip[2], 'r')

ax.plot(x1, y1[:,0], 'bo')
ax.plot(x1, y1[:,1], 'go')
ax.plot(x1, y1[:,2], 'ro')
```

This might be closer to what you want:

[image]